# String-separated arguments in LaTeX

Tags: macros, tex-core

One of the features I like best in Plain TeX is the ability to write macros with arguments separated by a sensible delimiter. For example

```
\def\translate#1 = #2 (#3){...}
```

What is the LaTeX way of doing this?
I know that this syntax is backward compatible, but as `\rm` instead of `\textrm` it is not idiomatic.

Comment: `\newcommand{\translate}{}\def\translate#1 = #2 (#3){...}`. But I don't think I'd ever use such syntax for my commands.

Comment: that is the latex way (but mostly it's  avoided except in special contexts that have custom syntax like tikz paths) `\NewDocumentCommand` `t` argument type allows some limited delimited arguments,

Comment: latex commands having a consistent syntax is a _feature_

Comment: such a definition is (perhaps) OK for a private shortcut, but not really a usable interface for a command used by others `\translate a = b (c)` works, but mandatory spaces is weird `\translate a=b (c)`  doesn't parse at all.

Comment: I suspect `sensible` may be in the eye of the beholder here ;).

Comment: The LaTeX way to define such a command is probably not to use this syntax but, instead, to use pgf or latex3 keys to define key-value pairs that are passed as an optional argument so that the command is used as `\translate[key=val, style..]{...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since expl3 is now hyped as part of LaTeX 2ε, I see no reason not to consider expl syntax to be LaTeX—be aware that with `\cs_new:Npn` you get a message in case a command already defined is about to be overridden:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \translate #1~=~#2~(#3) {Argument~1:~#1;~Argument~2:~#2;~Argument~3:~#3.}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

[\translate A = B (C)]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In pre-expl3-days I might have done:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\translate{%
  \def\translate#1 = #2 (#3){Argument 1: #1; Argument 2: #2; Argument 3: #3.}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

[\translate A = B (C)]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to have arbitrary amounts of explicit space tokens surrounding arguments removed I
might have combined a routine
`\UD@TrimAllSurroundSpaceAndOneLevelOfBraces{<action>}{<argument>}`
with grabbing delimited arguments one by one, taking prevention of brace-removal at the time of argument-grabbing into account:

```latex
\makeatletter
%%//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
%% SECTION EXPANDABLE REMOVAL OF LEADING AND TRAILING SPACES.
%%
%%   The obscure case of removing several leading/trailing spaces was taken 
%%   into consideration.
%%
%%   Removal of spaces was implemented in a way where no brace-stripping from
%%   the arguments takes place. 
%%   Explicit-catcode-1/2-character-token-pairs remain untouched.
%%
%%   Spaces interspersing the argument or hidden within braces will be left in
%%   place.
%%
%%   The arguments themselves do not get expanded.
%%
%%   (For some obscure reason I don't remember any more I needed this in the
%%    past.)
%%
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange,
%% \UD@removespace, \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@removespace{\UD@Exchange{ }{\def\UD@removespace}{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only spaces):
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}{}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is a catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has a leading
%%                        explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked does not have a
%%                        leading explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with a space-token
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does have a
%%                                       leading explicit space-token>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does not have a
%%                                       a leading explicit space-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
      \string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB.#1 }{}%
    }{}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB{%
  \long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB#1 {%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
    {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
     \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
  }%
}%
%%==============================================================================
%% \UD@TrimAllLeadSpace{<action>}{<argument>} 
%%..............................................................................
%%   expandably removes all leading spaces from  <argument> in case at least
%%   one leading space is present. 
%%   Then
%%     <action>{<argument without leading spaces>}
%%   is performed.
%%==============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@TrimAllLeadSpace[2]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@TrimAllLeadSpaceLoop{#2}{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@TrimAllLeadSpaceLoop[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{#1}{%
    \expandafter\UD@TrimAllLeadSpaceLoop\expandafter{\UD@removespace#1}{#2}%
  }{\UD@stopromannumeral#2{#1}}%
}%
%%==============================================================================
%% \UD@TrimAllTrailSpace{<action>}{<argument>} 
%%..............................................................................
%%   expandably removes all trailing spaces from  <argument> in case at least
%%   one trailing space is present. 
%%   Then
%%     <action>{<argument without trailing spaces>}
%%   is performed.
%%==============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@TrimAllTrailSpace[2]{%
   \romannumeral\UD@TrimTrailSpaceLoop{#2 }{}{#1}{}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@TrimTrailSpaceLoop[4]{%
  % in a loop shuffle space-delimited arguments from #1 to #2
  % until #1 is blank, i.e. empty or containing explicit space
  % tokens only.
  %
  % #1 - the remaining argument from which space-delimited bits
  %      are to be shuffled to #2.
  % #2 - argument without trailing spaces gathered so far.
  % #3 - <action>.
  % #4 - separator when appending stuff to #2; empty in 1st
  %      iteration, explicit space token in subsequent iterations.
  %
  % Shuffling requires a routine for removing the 1st space-delimited
  % argument from #1 - that is "\UD@RemoveFirstSpaceDelimited#1".
  %
  % Shuffling also requires a routine for extracting the 1st space-
  % delimited argument from #1 - that is
  % "\romannumeral\UD@keepFirstSpaceDelimited{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}".
  %
  \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#3{#2}}{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter
      \UD@Exchange
      \expandafter{\romannumeral\UD@keepFirstSpaceDelimited{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}}{#2#4}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@TrimTrailSpaceLoop
      \expandafter{\UD@RemoveFirstSpaceDelimited#1}%
    }{#3}{ }%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveFirstSpaceDelimited{\long\def\UD@RemoveFirstSpaceDelimited#1 {}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@StartExtractFirstSpaceDelimitedloop{%
  \long\def\UD@StartExtractFirstSpaceDelimitedloop#1 {{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@keepFirstSpaceDelimited[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@keepFirstSpaceDelimitedLoop\expandafter{\UD@StartExtractFirstSpaceDelimitedloop#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@keepFirstSpaceDelimitedLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherBlank\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{%
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}}{}%
  }{%
    \expandafter\UD@keepFirstSpaceDelimitedLoop\expandafter{\UD@@KeepFirstSpaceDelimited#1}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@@KeepFirstSpaceDelimited{\long\def\UD@@KeepFirstSpaceDelimited#1#2 {{#1}}}%
%%==============================================================================
%% \UD@TrimAllSurroundSpaceAndOneLevelOfBraces{<action>}{<argument>} 
%%..............................................................................
%%   expandably removes all leading and trailing spaces from  <argument>
%%   that are present. 
%%   Then removes one level of surrounding braces if present[1].
%%   Then
%%     <action>{<argument without leading and trailing spaces and with one level of surrounding braces removed if previously present>}
%%   is performed.
%%   [1] This way you can hide spaces that shall not be removed by placing
%%       arguments inside curly braces.
%%==============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@TrimAllSurroundSpaceAndOneLevelOfBraces[2]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@TrimAllLeadSpace{\UD@TrimAllTrailSpace{\UD@Bracecheck{#1}}}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@Bracecheck[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#2}{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}{%
      \UD@stopromannumeral#1#2%
    }{\UD@stopromannumeral#1{#2}}%
  }{\UD@stopromannumeral#1{#2}}%
}%
%%
%% EOF SECTION EXPANDABLE REMOVAL OF LEADING AND TRAILING SPACES.
%%//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

\newcommand*\translate{\grabtranslate@equal{}}%
\@ifdefinable\grabtranslate@equal{\long\def\grabtranslate@equal#1={\expandafter\grabtranslate@leftparen\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{}}}%
\@ifdefinable\grabtranslate@leftparen{\long\def\grabtranslate@leftparen#1#2({\expandafter\grabtranslate@rightparen\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}{#1}{}}}%
\@ifdefinable\grabtranslate@rightparen{\long\def\grabtranslate@rightparen#1#2#3){\expandafter\translate@inner\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#3}{#1}{#2}{}}}%
\newcommand\translate@inner[3]{%
  \UD@TrimAllSurroundSpaceAndOneLevelOfBraces{%
    \UD@TrimAllSurroundSpaceAndOneLevelOfBraces{%
      \UD@TrimAllSurroundSpaceAndOneLevelOfBraces{\innertranslate}{#3}%
    }{#2}%
  }{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\innertranslate[3]{%
  \texttt{\frenchspacing\detokenize{Argument 1: |#1|; Argument 2: |#2|; Argument 3: |#3|.}}%
}%

\makeatother


\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\translate A = B (C)

\translate A= B (C)

\translate A =B (C)

\translate A=B(C)

\translate A=B( C )

\translate {A} = {B} ({C})

\translate {A}= {B} ({C})

\translate {A} ={B} ({C})

\translate {A}={B}({C})

\translate {A}={B}( {C} )

The spaces inside the curly braces are kept:

\translate { A } = { B } ({ C })

\translate { A }= { B } ({ C })

\translate { A } ={ B } ({ C })

\translate { A }={ B }({ C })

\translate { A }={ B }( { C } )

Test with brace-groups not surrounding arguments but as components of arguments:

\translate {A}A = {B}B ({C}C)

\translate {A}A= {B}B ({C}C)

\translate {A}A ={B}B ({C}C)

\translate {A}A={B}B({C}C)

\translate {A}A={B}B( {C}C )

Spaces surrounding arguments are removed, spaces between components of arguments are kept:

\translate {A} A = {B} B ({C} C)

\translate {A} A= {B} B ({C} C)

\translate {A} A ={B} B ({C} C)

\translate {A} A={B} B({C} C)

\translate {A} A={B} B( {C} C )

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, with such macro-mechanisms for grabbing and pre-processing arguments, error-messages might turn more inscrutable as some might occur while processing internal macros which the end user might not be aware of without reading the commented source of the package in question.

And in practice you will rarely need code for removing an arbitrary amount of leading and trailing explicit space tokens where with user-provided arguments no token (but tokens defined in terms of `\outer`) is forbidden as its occurrence in the user-provided argument might break the mechanism.

In practice code for removing at most one leading explicit space and one trailing explicit space, using some argument-delimiter for denoting the end of the argument which the user may not provide as a component of the argument as otherwise the mechanism would break, is sufficient.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Besides this I don't care about the rule of not defining document-level-commands with programming-level-constructs: Often I need document-level-commands which work out entirely via expansion. `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` etc is not handy in this regard as with argument-types pre-processing is sort of a black box where you are not allowed to know about the amount of expansion steps and thus are not allowed to have full control. But this discussion already took place. It was unsatisfactory back then and I don't think the claqueurs of that time want to be any wiser today.

Comment: Wow. Absolutely astonishing code, and will repay close study.

Comment: @sgmoye I added some commenting.